# How to import projection into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, luciadmap

I have four files: `.prj`, `.qpj`, `.shp` and `.shx`.

They are properly read by [Luciad](http://www.luciad.com/) (it seems that only `.shp` and `.prj` are necessary for that).

Now I would like to import shapes into QGIS **taking into account projection** (that doesn't happen). I'm using "*Add Vector Layer*" option for this, maybe that's the problem?

I searched for it a lot and from what I understand `.qpj` is some *QGIS* equivalent of `.prj`. Mine look quite similar. But I'm still not sure which *CRS* should I use and how, I guess it should be somehow possible with those files.

My `.prj`:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

My `.qpj`:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

How do I know that projection isn't applied? I can only suppose that - this is example comparision between QGIS layer and Luciad map result (expected):

[image]

Maybe I shouldn't mention Luciad here, because it's not that related, but that's how I know that my data are good.

**EDIT**: I see that `.qpj`/`.prj` file is used (if none of them is present, QGIS asks me for a CRS, but it doesn't seem to make any difference when I choose just default *WGS 84*). However, for some reason something (CRS?) from those files isn't applied in the way I want - like in Luciad.

Comment: what happens if you choose CRS 7030 in Set CRS?

Comment: @ElioDiaz likely nothing as the two occurrences of 7030 in EPSG are a transformation and an ellipsoid. There's no CRS with an ID of 7030.

Comment: My guess is that Luciad's display is not pseudo-plate carree but some other projected CRS or orthographic emulating a 3D view. When you use a geographic CRS QGIS (or ArcGIS), the angular units are treated as if they're linear. That will stretch data east-west as you move away from the equator.

Comment: the shape will depend on what the project's crs is set to, look in the lower right corner

Comment: @ElioDiaz you mean right click on layer -> "Set Layer CRS"? Could you help mi with finding it?

Comment: @IanTurton should it change immediately when I change CRS on the layer? I tried various things (after removing .pjr and .qpj and setting CRS manually when importing a layer), but the shape stays always the same - only its position changes.

Comment: @mkennedy what you meant by "pseudo-plate carree" (especially carree, I don't understand this word)? the real problem is when I generate fixed-size buffer, it looks good (equals) in QGIS but gots malformed when I import it to Luciad...

Answer (score 0):

Worked when I set project CRS to `WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator` (*EPSG:3857*) **before importing layer**.